# what is the cause of "cluster wait" in oracle ADB?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

60% of query execution time is spent in "cluster wait" in ORACLE ADW database.
What causes this cluster wait?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a wait class related to RAC nodes, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/classes-of-wait-events.html#GUID-B30B0811-0FDC-40FC-92FC-F6726CE94736. In the SQL Monitor report you posted the screenshot of, you can look at the Activity bar and see what individual wait events you are seeing. You can also look at the execution plan in the report to see where those waits are happening.